# How to get estimated shipping address before placing order magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

I want to get estimated shipping adddress for a custom controle of country so how to prodceed please and thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Event observer to get estimated shipping address before place order.
Please find below steps to get shipping address.

Step-1: Create custom Module

```
    Path- app/code/Custom/Module
```

Step-2: Create **events.xml** under module etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_submit_before">
       <observer name="custom_module_observer_index" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\Index" />
   </event>
</config>
```

Step-3: Create Observer to execute event below path

```
    app/code/Custom/Module/Observer/Index.php
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class Index implements ObserverInterface
{
     protected $messageManager;
     protected $scopeConfig;
     protected $checkoutSession;
     protected $logger;
   protected $_coreSession;
   protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

     public function __construct(
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
     \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
                    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;

    }
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  { 



         $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
         $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
         $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
         $store_id = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
         $this->logger->info("storeid==>".$store_id."<");

         // get shipping address

         $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); 
         $city = $shippingAddress->getCity();
         $country = $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
         $this->logger->info("shippingAddress=>".$country."<");
         $this->logger->info("shippingAddress=>".$city."<");

        } 


  }
```

**Note**

Comment: thanks for your replay i will test this code immediatly

Comment: now how to pass variable from this observer to onother please i need this estimated country to be present in an observer that belong to event  payment_method_is_active so how to to

Comment: where are you pass this variable?

Comment: you can set variable in custom session and get it where you want.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-set-unset-session-magento-2.html

Comment: I have to test on country of shipping addreess and then set status of order according to this country

Comment: you can set order status in observer for this country.means you change order status when you get particular country wise

Comment: can you explain more *

Comment: showing me OrderId = null